# Folder creation and checking existence

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, directory, onedrive

I need help with the SkyDrive API for Windows Phone.

Basically I've been playing around with the API for a while and I've got the hang of it on how it works now what I try to do is implement a backup like method in my app.

So far this is my code:

```
private async void CreateBackupBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    #region Sort To Folders // ONLINE
    client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
    var operationResult = await client.GetAsync("me/skydrive/files?filter=folders");
    dynamic result = operationResult.Result;
    List<object> folder = result.data;

    foreach (dynamic item in folder)
    {
        if (item.id == "Saved DATA")
        {
            folderId = item.id;
            break;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    if (folderId == "")
    {
        var folderData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        folderData.Add("name", "Saved DATA");
        LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(this.session);
        LiveOperationResult operationResult1 = await liveClient.PostAsync("me/skydrive", folderData);
        dynamic result1 = operationResult1.Result;
        folderId = result1.id;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(folderId, "", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
}
```

So now when the user opens up the Backup page, once signed in the backup button is visible. He clicks on it and it creates a folder on SkyDrive called `Saved DATA`. This all works perfectly BUT say the user creates the folder and goes a page back, comes back and decides he wants to create the backup, I get an error saying that that

> the resource name already exists "Saved DATA"

Basically I can't create this folder because it already exists.

I need to solve this problem. I need a way to avoid this problem. What's a good solution to this?

Comment: you need to check for folder name. when you create a folder, its name is Saved DATA and not its id.

   if (item.name == "Saved DATA")
   {
      folderId = item.id;
      break;
   }

Comment: Thank you! That seem to fix it. Also, do you know if there is any way of checking if the upload of a file to skydrive is complete? There seems to be no completed even anymore.

Comment: LiveConnectClient.UploadCompleted event is available for windows phone live sdk. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#uploading_files

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look.